# Regression dataset with categorical features

Tags: dataset, regression, data, categorical-data, open-source

I have thought of a regression technique that I want to try on several datasets. I would like these datasets to have the following properties:

- Be a tabular dataset (no images).
- Have at least 20k rows, and ideally around 100k.
- Have some categorical variables with many levels (at least a variable with 100 levels or more).
- Ideally, the target should have long tails.

Does anyone any public dataset with these properties? I have found [the stack overflow developer survey](https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stack-overflow-2018-developer-survey) to work for me, but I'd like to have some more datasets with such structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of a post on Open Data: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/17679/regression-dataset-with-categorical-features.

Comment: @Dave Page not found

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam He posted the same question on Open Data and has deleted it. I think he deleted the wrong one.

Comment: Yeah I deleted it there, I probably dit it worng